# Adding $data to view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello when I add my data to my view it pushes it out of the container. Why does that happen I have a return and NULL, TRUE. All the other controllers are OK just footer controller not working when have data variable.

```
public function index() {
$data['powered'] = $this->config->item('getTitle');

if (file_exists(APPPATH . $this->config->item('theme_path') . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer.tpl')) {
return $this->load->view($this->config->item('theme_path') . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer.tpl', $data, NULL, TRUE);
} else {
return $this->load->view($this->config->item('theme_path') . 'default/template/common/footer.tpl', $data, NULL, TRUE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how data is to be passed to a view.

Let's start with passing a simple array of data to a view:

```
$this->load->view('some_view', $data); // $data is your array
```

The method given above also takes a third argument which is required when you want your view to be returned back. This might be done when you want to process the rendered view. To do this use the code below:

```
// notice the third argument. by default it is false
// ensure that you are assigning the view call to a variable
$view_data = $this->load->view('some_view', $data, true);
```

According to me you need to change your code to the following:

```
public function index() {
  $data['powered'] = $this->config->item('getTitle');

  if (file_exists(APPPATH . $this->config->item('theme_path') . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer.tpl')) {
    return $this->load->view($this->config->item('theme_path') . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/footer.tpl', $data);
  } else {
    return $this->load->view($this->config->item('theme_path') . 'default/template/common/footer.tpl', $data);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I had the NULL it worked but when I added the data did not. I  removed null when added data and worked.